# How to Button on Toolbar in android

Tags: android, textview, toolbar

I am working on android application , i want to add button on toolbar. I am using menu item but this coming in dropdown but i want simple text or button(forward button or reset button) on toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your menu element

```
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

To see icon instead drop menu

Answer (score 0):

Write your menu as

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.toolbar.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search" 
        android:menuCategory="secondary"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="action_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_share_white_24dp"
        android:menuCategory="secondary"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="action_share"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

to see your menu items as icons

Comment: Why `android:menuCategory="secondary"`?